# How randomize quicksort differs from randomize selection algorithm in terms of time complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

Using `randomize_quicksort()`, we know the average case complexity is *O(nlgn)* since we pick the pivot in random process. However, when I was looking to **randomize** selection algorithm, where we also choose the pivot randomly similar to the randomize_quicksort(), we ended up with O(n^2) complexity in worst case. I don't understand what makes it run in quadratic time although we are using the same strategy of picking the pivot element.

Thank you

Comment: Quicksort is also O(n^2) in the *worst case*.

Answer (score 1):

Your question already contains the answer. You're talking about an average case for the quick sort and the worst case for the selection algorithm. It's not the same thing. Both algorithms are quadratic in the worst case.